# Explanatory notes (for BibTex or BibLaTeX "fields") showing on mouse-hover (a.k.a. tooltip) when hovering over references' fields

Tags: bibtex, xetex, fancytooltips

Imagine you have a bibtex reference entry with many different (also non-standard: called e.g. **this1** here) "fields", as such:

```
@online{foo,
  title = {...},
  url = {...},
  urldate = {...},
  this1 = {...},
  this2 = {...},
  this3 = {...},
  that1 = {...},
  that2 = {...},
  .... = {...},}
```

When the references are formatted this way, then the user who **writes** the LaTeX document, obviously (more or less) remembers to which field (and context of that field) each field's contents refer, in the compiled document. But for the **reader** of the compiled LaTex document, this may not always be obvious (certainly with many non-standard "fields", where it would perhaps become too *crazy* to mark-up each different field with a different lay-out).

Sometimes, it is even difficult for the reader to understand where a certain field's contents stops and a new field's contents begin.

Therefor, I propose a workflow which creates a **tooltip on mouse-hover over a certain field's context**, which would show a **description** of that field.

Ideally, it would also envelop the field's contents in a frame (preferably in a frame that would show up; or if not, just under-line text, or make it bold; or if not possible, perhaps to 
colour the field's contents) when somebody hovers over part of any field's contents, so that the reader can easily understand where a certain field's contents begin and end.

Comment: While I do understand the attraction of such play things as tooltips: If they are needed to explain a text, you should better rewrite the text. As an example: if it is unclear that a number is a DOI, write DOI: before the number instead of expecting people to constantly use the mouse to hover over the text to get popup and explanations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer But, to be unambiguously clear, I argue, one should almost write the description of every single field inside the field's output. The title of a book, for example, might contain comma's, which one might also use to separate the outputs of different fields, making it very difficult to spot where one field begins and the former ends. Sometimes, an author has multiple names, of which you might separate one by a comma: yet more space for unambiguous interpretation: where does the title begin? ...

Comment: ... Certainly, when the reader of the document is not very language proficient in the language which a certain reference contains. Sometimes, a reference is e.g. a webpage with 2 scanned news articles, of which you want to include the information about the 2 scanned news articles ... You can see how that would require even more punctuation marks, and creates a situation which is very difficult to understand, if the proposed workflow is not created ...

Comment: ... And even the description of a field (e.g. *Publisher:*) could also be present in the contents of another field (e.g. a book can be named: *Publisher: Copenhagen*). Sub-titles (which can be multiple) are other difficult ones to spot (certainly when one only separates them by a double point, which as I said can occur in many other instances creating ambiguity).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thinking of your thoughts (which hopes to include all descriptive information already **inside** a non-interactive environment), would you perhaps propose that it would be better to have footnotes organized into a table, where the rows are each different bibliographic entries, and the columns represent descriptions of fields? I can see an advantage for that, but I think that almost no paper would have sufficient width to include all fields.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- Another good way to proceed (following your thoughts) could be to simply type-set the description of all fields in 1 particular way (e.g. in bold-face) which is NOT present in any of the field's contents, so that it is very clear what each field is about and where each field ends. But my objection is that such mark-up would be confusing, as the rest of the document might use bold-face (or colours) in a different way. Similar objections could be raised, when one would use only colours (to colour each type of field differently and) to create a legend of fields' descriptions.

Comment: I think that you should assume that your readers have some basic intelligence. For hundreds of years people where able to read and understand books without tooltips so don't start to argue that without them a text is not understable.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is based on the assumption that no reader has ever since not understood, or has ever since not mis-understood (parts of) texts. I think the assumption is not correct. I think there have been many new ingenious (a lot, but not all of which were technological) features in writing documents to be able to retain original meaning more accurately over longer periods of time. At the same time, some readers might not have any basic intelligence at all, regarding to the text presented to them (they might e.g. not know the language or context of a bibliographic reference) ...

Comment: ... At the same time, one can also try to increase the *speed* of comprehension. I am thinking also about future historians, who, in many hundred thousands of years, might have a hard time understanding a bibliographic reference. I am also thinking about other software, which might be able to analyze documents precisely (e.g. based on the proposed workflow) so to index bibliographic references.

Comment: tooltips don't prevent people from misunderstanding text, and adding more levels doesn't make a text easier to read. E.g. texts with more than one footnote level are for specialists. Also I doubt that your tooltips will still be readable in 100 year.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can see intelligent remarks there. But, perhaps as an addition I would like to say, that for *some purposes*, and for *some people* who have those purposes, it might be best to include such meta-description into the text anyway (not everybody has to hover over the fields, or look at the codes inside a .pdf). I just see it as an unfortunate thing that people nicely code their references, but a lot of such work is lost on out-put. I speak from personal experience when trying to understand professional **bibliography of**-books, and indexing those: there was always ambiguity.